# Creating an executable jar from 2 other executable jar

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, executable-jar

I want to create one executable jar file from 2 other executable jar files.
So i'm working on a betting project and i have 2 projects, Client and Monitor. I created their jar files and everything is fine.
But is there a way to combine their jar files so i can run both from 1 jar file so i don't have to run each time both client.jar and monitor.jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to combine those two jar files to one jar file, however, every jar file can only have one main class that gets run if no main class is specified via command line.

This means you would have to either create a new main class which executes both previous main classes, or end up running the same jar file twice with different arguments.

However, I would not recommend combining those two. There will be a reason those two are seperate projects, so why would you combine them both? Also, if one jar file crashes, the second will still run.

If you still want to combine those two I see two options:

- Either you create a third project (I assume maven?) which depends on both projects and contains the new main class
- Or, if you run into class loading problems, as the first approach will put the jars into a jar file, you could use the maven shade plugin to get one flat jar file. This is sometimes necessary, if you use third party libs where you cannot control how resources are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Create another project and include that two jar files in the third one's class path. 
Now you can copy the same code from `main` methods from jar A and Jar B, and paste that in  `main` method of jar C. now you can run only the Jar C.

Answer (score 0):

> But is there a way to combine their jar files so i can run both from 1
>   jar

There is no easy way but to unzip and then get all of the contents of all of the jar files to be extracted, and then zipped up again into one jar.

You need to cautious in the merge of your Manifest.MF file which defines your entry point of main class having main method.

> Note: But I am not sure if you will be able to have 2 main class in
>   your manifest file. You might have to execute via classpath in such
>   case.

Answer (score 0):

Im using netbeans for java.
The easiest way that you want is to create new project and add the 2 jar files as library to your project